# Ruby/Rails scan/match with regex from a tag to another out of text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

In the following content samples, I wrapped the lines to make it easier to read on Stackoverflow (so you don't have to scroll to the right to look at the examples).

Content A:

```
"Lorem Ipsum\r\n
[img]http://example.org/first.jpg[/img]\r\n
[img]http://example.org/second.jpg[/img]\r\n
more lorem ipsum ..."
```

Content B:

```
"Lorem Ipsum\r\n
[img caption="Sample caption"]http://example.org/third.jpg[/img]
[img]http://example.org/fourth.jpg[/img]"
```

Content C:

```
"Lorem Ipsum [img]http://example.org/fifth.jpg[/img]\r\n
more lorem ipsum\r\n\r\n
[img caption="Some other caption"]http://example.org[/img]"
```

What I've tried:

```
content.match(/\[img\]([^<>]*)\[\/img\]/imu)
return example: "[img]...[/img]\r\n[img]...[/img]
content.scan(/\[img\]([^<>]*)\[\/img\]/imu)
return example: "...[/img]\r\n[img]..."
```

What I would like to accomplish when running the scan/match/regex solution over the above 3 Content Examples is to get every occurence of `[img]...[/img]` and `[img caption="?"]...[/img]` and put it in an array for later use.

```
Array
  1 : A : [img]http://example.org/first.jpg[/img]
  2 : A : [img]http://example.org/second.jpg[/img]
  3 : B : [img caption="Sample caption"]http://example.org/third.jpg[/img]
  4 : B : [img]http://example.org/fourth.jpg[/img]
  5 : C : [img]http://example.org/fifth.jpg[/img]
  6 : C : [img caption="Some other caption"]http://example.org[/img]
```

It would also be helpful to limit the "stripped content" to only where there is an open and closign tag, meaning when there is a `[img]` / `[img caption="?"]` and a missing `[/img]` afterwards, to ignore it.

I've read the http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html up and down but can't find anything that seem to work for this.

Update:

So I figured that this:

```
\[img([^<>]*)\]([^<>]*)\[\/img\]
```

will find either:

```
[img]something[/img]
```

and:

```
[img caption="something"]something[/img]
```

Now I just need to know how to catch every occurence inside the different contents. I can always just get it from the first to the last [img][/img] tags, so when there is other Lorem Ipsum in between it will get grabbed too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`/\[img(?:\s+caption=".+")?\].+?\[\/img\]/`](http://rubular.com/r/aQKZviwOzG) to scan the documents:

```
regex = /\[img(?:\s+caption=".+")?\].+?\[\/img\]/

text = <<EOT
Lorem Ipsum
[img]http://example.org/first.jpg[/img]
[img]http://example.org/second.jpg[/img]
more lorem ipsum ...

Content B:

Lorem Ipsum
[img caption="Sample caption"]http://example.org/third.jpg[/img]
[img]http://example.org/fourth.jpg[/img]

Content C:

Lorem Ipsum [img]http://example.org/fifth.jpg[/img]
more lorem ipsum

[img caption="Some other caption"]http://example.org[/img]
EOT

array = text.scan(regex)
puts array
```

Which generates:

```
[img]http://example.org/first.jpg[/img]
[img]http://example.org/second.jpg[/img]
[img caption="Sample caption"]http://example.org/third.jpg[/img]
[img]http://example.org/fourth.jpg[/img]
[img]http://example.org/fifth.jpg[/img]
[img caption="Some other caption"]http://example.org[/img]
```

If you want to ignore the tags and only grab the content, change the regexp to:

```
regex = /\[img(?:\s+caption=".+")?\](.+?)\[\/img\]/
```

Running again with that change returns:

```
http://example.org/first.jpg
http://example.org/second.jpg
http://example.org/third.jpg
http://example.org/fourth.jpg
http://example.org/fifth.jpg
http://example.org
```

([Rubular proof](http://rubular.com/r/iBYvvzCoLW))

If you need to look for different tags, you can generate an "OR" list easily:

```
Regexp.union(%w[foo img bar])
=> /foo|img|bar/
```

If you need to make sure that "magic" characters are escaped beforehand:

```
Regexp.union(%w[foo img bar].map{ |s| Regexp.escape(s) })
```

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately for you, I've already solved this one in my own app!

Given that `@tags` is an array of tags (like `["img"]`):

```
regex = /\[(#{@tags.join("|")})\s*(.*?)?\/?\](?:(.*?)\[\/\1\])?/
matches = content.scan(regex)
```

Full example:

```
require 'pp'

@tags = %w(img)
regex = /\[(#{@tags.join("|")})\s*(.*?)?\/?\](?:(.*?)\[\/\1\])?/

content = <<-EOF
  Lorem Ipsum\r\n
  [img]http://example.org/first.jpg[/img]\r\n
  [img]http://example.org/second.jpg[/img]\r\n
  more lorem ipsum ..."
  Content B:

  "Lorem Ipsum\r\n
  [img caption="Sample caption"]http://example.org/third.jpg[/img]
  [img]http://example.org/fourth.jpg[/img]"
  Content C:

  "Lorem Ipsum [img]http://example.org/fifth.jpg[/img]\r\n
  more lorem ipsum\r\n\r\n
  [img caption="Some other caption"]http://example.org[/img]"
EOF

matches = content.scan(regex)
pp matches
```

And output:

```
[["img", "", "http://example.org/first.jpg"],
 ["img", "", "http://example.org/second.jpg"],
 ["img", "caption=\"Sample caption\"", "http://example.org/third.jpg"],
 ["img", "", "http://example.org/fourth.jpg"],
 ["img", "", "http://example.org/fifth.jpg"],
 ["img", "caption=\"Some other caption\"", "http://example.org"]]
```